# Single Letsencrypt certificate for multiple domains

Tags: nginx, digital-ocean, lets-encrypt, certbot

I was trying to generate letsencrypt certificate for multiple domains using -d option in nginx server. As shown in the following link [letsencryptformultipledomains](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/letsencrypt-for-multiple-domains-on-nginx). But I was getting following errors.
I gone through several examples but didn't work.

- Failed authorization procedure urn:acme:error:connection :: The server could not connect to the client to verify the domain::test.xxxx.com
- Could not connect to `test.xxxx.com` and `demo.xxxx.com`

Comment: What is your nginx config for the multiple domains?

Comment: Is the domain you're using a real domain with DNS that can be accessed externally or something you use internally?